# What physical property does the crossover frequency in an ionic conductor represent; why is conductivity constant below and increasing above it?

Tags: conductors, ions, transport-phenomena, amorphous-solids

After reading an article about ionic transport[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZM7l.jpg), I remain confused about why the behavior illustrated in Fig. 1 of the article happens. (Figure 1 is shown below.)

Specifically, why is the conductivity constant at low frequencies and why does it increase at high frequencies? What is the physical mechanism behind this behavior?

My intuition suggests that the opposite should occur by the following mechanism: at low frequencies, ions have time to respond to the applied potential in both directions, and conductivity is constant as long as this holds true. At the same time, electrons can also contribute to conductivity because they will be able to respond as quickly as ions.  Above a certain frequency, however, ions will no longer be able to respond in time, so conductivity will decrease. However, as shown in the figure, conductivity increases above the crossover frequency. How does this happen?

[image: Conductivity data for a commercial soda-lime silica glass (glass slide) plotted as a function of frequency at different temperatures. The d.c. conductivities are the plateau values (data from M. H. Wu, Aberdeen, UK).]

1. M.D. Ingram. Amorphous Materials: Ionic Transport, in: K.H.J. Buschow, R.W. Cahn, M.C. Flemings, B. Ilschner, E.J. Kramer, S. Mahajan, P. Veyssière (Eds.) Encyclopedia of Materials: Science and Technology, Elsevier, Oxford. 2001, pp. 204-211.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a measurement artifact:

- the conductivity is very low, resistance is high
- When measuring there is some capacitance in parallel due to contacts and cables.
- the conductivity of this capacitance will rise and dominate at higher frequencies

All the curves seem to approach a similar high frequency conductivity, which is in support of the stray capacitance, which would be also similar irrespective of the test temperature. Also, the caption doesn't discuss the high frequency part, but only DC behavior

Comment: No, this is a characteristic of the material.

Comment: @JosephThiebes If the material contains particles or segregations that support internal electronic transport, you will also see the capacitive coupling between these particles at high frequencies.